# file_get_contents not returning php code

Tags: php

I'm trying to define a string as a combination of hard coded characters and of the contents of another file. What I have tried is this.

```
$html = "<h1>
           ".file_get_contents("file.php", TRUE)."
        <h1>";
```

The problem is that only raw text is being returned from file.php. Whatever it is that PHP is supposed to echo isn't being echoed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) to do that:

```
function generate_h1()
{
    ob_start();
    include('file.php');

    return '<h1>' . ob_get_clean() . '</h1>';
}

$html = generate_h1();
```

See also: [`ob_start()`](http://www.php.net/ob_start)  [`ob_get_clean()`](http://www.php.net/ob_get_clean%28%29)

Comment: Is there any way that I could put parameters on the URL? I don't think it's possible to pass variables along the URL path with require() or include(), is it?

Comment: @Lance if you're passing a URL to include(), you can pass parameters. I would advice against include() from remote location though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `include` or `require` instead of `file_get_contents`. `file_get_contents` won't execute a local file, it just gets its contents - the plain-text PHP code.

Comment: Well, $html = "<h1>".require("file.php")."</h1>"; wont work though. Is there something with a buffer that I need to do?

Comment: Yes, @Jack's answer gives you info on doing that.

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents() returns the actual source of a file and it does not use it as a script. What you need is either

```
include 'file.php'; //or
require 'file.php';
```

or better yet

```
include_once 'file.php';
require_once 'file.php';
```

This is better in case you have functions declared in file.php. If you include a file twice it will throw an error saying that a function has been declared more than once. so include_once if it's something that you can live without in case something happens to the file or require_once which will result a fatal error if the file does not exist.